# Data collector mobile app with mapping capabilities

Tags: qgis, geoserver, javascript, android, data-collection

At work we have a GIS solution platform with 50+ GB of data in a Postgres cluster. Almost all tables have spatial columns. We have several clients consuming this information for different needs.

I'm looking for the best mobile solution for field data collection and visualization.

There is an old question about this, but since it is 4 years old, probably a lot of things had changed.
[Open Source equivalent to Collector for ArcGIS to use with QGIS/PostGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83482/open-source-equivalent-to-collector-for-arcgis-to-use-with-qgis-postgis/83554)

To summarize, the main requirements are:
- Mobile app (Android mandatory, iOS non-mandatory)
- Base maps (OSM, Google, Bing, etc)
- View OGC mapping data (WMS, WFS, etc)
- View forms with specific information of every layer 
- Capable of adding new geometries (point, polygon, polyline) to a layer, and adding specific alphanumeric data using an associated dynamic form. This data can hit an WFS-T service
- Work offline. That includes basemaps (like a local tile cache), and vector data
- If some data was collected offline, it need to sync that data with the service/database

And in top of that, some clients have very specific requirements for their mobile apps. For instance, to some of them, the normal data collection app is enough, but maybe another client have a procedure in the field that requires special features. So, the possibility of development is really welcome, may be via an SDK or something similar.

What are the actual alternatives to accomplish this?

Comment: Old list does not seem to include GvSIG and Geopaparazzi http://downloads.gvsig.org/download/events/gvSIG-Festival/2o-gvSIG-Festival/reports/2o_gvSIG_Festival-Geopaparazzi.pdf.

Comment: Check GISCloud, we're using it for a mobile data collection project with a lighting vendor.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I am the founder of the company responsible for this app development.

The [Coral App](https://chaac.tech/coralapp/) might be a great solution for you.

It is a native data collection app available on both Android and IOS.

You can easily create mobile forms on the web dashboard. The form builder is simple to use. If you already have data sets, you can import them into the platform either in read-only or in edition mode.

You can organize your data in projects. Each project web-view include an interactive map and a tabular view.

On the mobile app, you can view the data layers on a map. You can add surveys using the forms created on the dashboard. The app support points, lines and polygons during the feature creation. The geometry is linked to the form and is determined when you build your forms.

There is also a REST API to link the solution to other solutions in real-time.

The devs are really responsive and can add custom features quickly.

There is a free plan for small projects. All their plans also include an unlimited number of users, so that's a plus for large organisations.

[image: coral app]

Comment: Does it support WMS and WFS, it's not stated in the web pages, but is one of the main requirements in the question

Comment: The framework we are using supports WMS and WFS, but we haven't implemented it yet. We drive out features based on our client's requirements.

Comment: You should edit your answer to mention you are associated with the product.    You mention you can add custom features, not sure how that would relate to WMS/WFS/WFS-T requirements of the question, you should expand the answer to address these points which are part of the stated requirements.